# select entire row with flexibility

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to select an entire row but skip the first 3 columns of the same row without using 'range()' command. What command can i use?

Comment: Why you won't use range ? Its made for

Comment: @Dorian  Because when i use range it is not flexible. I am unable to perform this command as shown below. There will be an error "application-defined or object-defined error"
Worksheets("sheets1").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 9)).copy_ Worksheets("sheets2").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 9))
I wanted to copy a range of cells in a single row and paste it on another sheet in as little lines as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Cells` and `Resize`:

[Range.Cells Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells)

[Range.Resize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

Depending on how you ask the question (skip first column or first column is), you can use the combination as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EntireSkipColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FR As Long: FR = 2
    Dim LR As Long: LR = 10
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long: j = 3  ' Skip first 3 columns
    For i = FR To LR
        Set rng = ws.Cells(i, j + 1).Resize(, ws.Columns.Count - j)
        With rng
            ' To check if the range is correct.
            Debug.Print .Address(False, False)
            ' Cycle Interior ColorIndex
            '.Interior.ColorIndex = i
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Sub EntireFirstColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FR As Long: FR = 2
    Dim LR As Long: LR = 10
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long: j = 4  ' Use 4 as the first column
    For i = FR To LR
        Set rng = ws.Cells(i, j).Resize(, ws.Columns.Count - j + 1)
        With rng
            ' To check if the range is correct.
            Debug.Print .Address(False, False)
            ' Cycle Interior ColorIndex
            '.Interior.ColorIndex = i
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

`Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)` is only used to move each result a row below.

```
Sub QualifyCellsToo()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    ' This is wrong:
    'Worksheets("sheets1").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 9)).Copy _
       Worksheets("sheets2").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 9))

    ' You have to qualify 'Cells', too:
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 4), _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 9)).Copy _
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 4), _
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 9))
    ' This is a long expression, so using variables is preferred.
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(3, 4), wsSource.Cells(3, 9))
    Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range(wsTarget.Cells(3, 4), wsTarget.Cells(3, 9))

            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
            rngTarget.Resize(10).Clear

    ' Copy values or formulas and formats using same sized ranges.
    rngSource.Copy rngTarget
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
    ' Copy values or formulas and formats using only the first cell
    ' of Target Range.
    rngSource.Copy rngTarget.Cells(1)
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)

    ' Copy values
    rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
    ' Copy values using target without '.Value'
    rngTarget = rngSource.Value
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: @user13316884: I've added 'QualifyCellsToo' to my answer.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake and giving me the solution:)

Comment: Feel free to accept helpful answers to your questions by ticking the green check mark and/or to upvote; would be helpful for guiding other users, too :-)